# Creating a Tensorflow and Pandas Environment

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, unicode

I using the following command to use modules in my machine learning work.

```
conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5
activate tensorflow
conda install pandas matplotlib jupyter notebook scipy scikit-learn nltk
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow keras
```

When i using import command in my ipython notebook

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

Following error is coming

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\sompatha\Anaconda2\envs\Ml\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2862, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)



  File "<ipython-input-1-eeff7c4f34af>", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np

  File "C:\Users\sompatha\Anaconda2\envs\Ml\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 126, in <module>
    from numpy.__config__ import show as show_config

  File "C:\Users\sompatha\Anaconda2\envs\Ml\lib\site-packages\numpy\__config__.py", line 5
    blas_mkl_info={'library_dirs': ['C:\Users\sompatha\Anaconda2\envs\ML\\Library\\lib'], 'define_macros': [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)], 'libraries': ['mkl_core_dll', 'mkl_intel_lp64_dll', 'mkl_intel_thread_dll'], 'include_dirs': ['C:\Users\sompatha\Anaconda2\envs\ML\\Library\\include']}
                                   ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

How to resolve this one ? Please help

Answer (score 2):

You are using old versions of conda and python.
The error tells you exactly what is going wrong: your escaped '\U' tells the interpreter there is a 8 digit code upcoming. That is not the case, the 's' is not valid in such a context.

The best thing to do: use up-to-date versions of the software packages.

The manual fix, go to:

```
C:\Users\sompatha\Anaconda2\envs\Ml\Lib\site-packages\numpy\__config__.py
```

And replace all single slashes in path references within this file with double slashes.
Repeat the process for any other import running into the UnicodeError. Your interpreter will tell you which file is holding you back